# Star Trek and Andromeda: are they contiguous?

Tags: star-trek, gene-roddenberry, andromeda

Gene Roddenberry created both Star Trek and Andromeda (or the idea for Andromeda, anyways).

Being that Andromeda is set thousands of years in the future, while Star Trek is hundreds of years, is Andromeda the continuation of the story of Star Trek? Are the two canons related?

Comment: I read this as "...are they contagious?" and I was going to answer "Of course they are, if you're on this website, you've been infected already..." lol

Comment: When some licensed Planet of The Apes crossover with ST: TOS comic happened recently I realized technically Apes is far enough in the future that it could work too with some very minor changes.  Ultimately any writer that destroys the Federation like Andromeda is fundamentally missing the point of Star Trek. That goes triple for when Discovery did it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No.

There are two events where both the CY (Commonwealth Year) and the Earth year are known: the year that Nietzsche published *Thus Spake Zarathustra* (6811 CY, published in four parts between 1883 and 1885) and the year that *The Bell X-1* broke the sound barrier (6869 CY, 1947).

We know that Earth joined the Systems Commonwealth in 7085 CY, which is therefore something like 2155 in our calendar - i.e. it's really only about 150 years in our future (around the time of the final season of *Enterprise*, i.e. the founding of the Federation - this is presumably a coincidence).  It is thousands of years old by this point, but without humanity (and then it continues for a long time again before Dylan Hunt comes along).

We also see events far in the future in *Star Trek*, e.g. we know that the ship from the *Enterprise* episode *Future Tense* was commissioned in 3040.  This doesn't match with events from the Andromeda universe at all.

As far as I know, we never see any of the Star Trek races in Andromeda, nor do we see any of the Andromeda races in Star Trek either (excepting humanity, of course).  The technology is also quite different.

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand, ANDROMEDA was originally intended to be a TREK series, set after the fall of the Federation.

The *Andromeda Ascendant* would have been another in the line of *Enterprises*, the Vulcans and Klingons were replaced with Vedrans and Nietzscheans, or something like that.

I always wished that this had been the show we got, we always heard about how great the Commonwealth was, but we never got to *see* it. By setting the story in the Trek-verse, it would have raised the stakes considerably.

After Roddenberry died, they took a bunch of story ideas he had and re-worked them. Earth: Final conflict was the other that made it on the air. Funny thing is, ANDROMEDA was originally going to be titled PHOENIX RISING, and ANDROMEDA was the title for another Roddenberry show. For some reason they either swapped titles or combined the show ideas.

Also, this wasn't the first time Roddenberry had a character named Dylan Hunt. The first was in a show called *Genesis II* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_(film)

"In the 1973 made-for-TV film Genesis II, which introduced the character and was intended as a pilot for a potential series, Hunt was played by Alex Cord. Hunt was a NASA scientist who became trapped in suspended animation in 1979, only to awaken 154 years later"

Comment: Do you have any sources for your claim of the intended link between *Andromeda* and the *Star Trek* universe?

Comment: @Beofett [TVTropes says this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Andromeda), which I've read somewhere else as well: `The show has its origins in a combination of two separate Roddenberry story ideas from the 1970s, one about a sentient starship and a second about a man from the past trying to piece the remnants of civilization back together after it has crumbled.` - Neither there nor where I remember it before is Star Trek mentioned.  And I can't seem find reference for the "two ideas" thing either, actually.

Comment: "From what I understand, ANDROMEDA was originally intended to be a TREK series, set after the fall of the Federation. " Discovery kinda picked up the idea in Season 3, they just did not go all the way into "total Collapse" territory. I think it might still play some role in the 4th Season.

Answer (score 1):

As broadcast, the two are completely independent universes.  However, there is strong evidence that the original intent was for them to be sequential.  With, what became Andromeda, showing a universe after the fall of the Federation.  Looking at it from that point of view, you can definitely see the similarities.  Humanity joined the Commonwealth and the Federation was founded at, essentially, the same point in Earth's history.  Each of the races in Andromeda parallel the ones in Trek:
Vedrans - Vulcans or maybe the precursor race
Humanity - Humanity
Nightsiders - Ferengi
Nietzscheans - Advanced Klingons
Magog - Borg (In reverse.  Ultra religious vs Cybernetic)

Often times, these races were done in a bit of parody, I believe.  Since the iconic traits of each race were exaggerated in Andromeda as verses Trek.

The technology in Andromeda is a legitimate outgrowth of that seen in TNG.  In the TNG era, the Federation was just beginning to experiment with wormhole or slipstream technology.  Andromeda shows that technology perfected.

The ship design is radically different though.  Trek took a very scientific and utilitarian view of ship design.  Andromeda uses a much more organic ship design.  Also, Andromeda's ships of the line are designed primarily for combat.  This could be a logical outgrowth of a Federation that had become fascistic and conquest oriented.  We see the beginnings of that movement during the TNG era, especially in DS9.  The Dominion War era was the end of the Federation's innocence.

Also, the use of highly evolved AIs has early parallels in Trek with Data and Lore.  The Picard series has really rounded that out and brought AIs, or Synths as they are called in Picard, in to being as fully rounded individuals.  Another thousand or two years of evolution of the technology may result in Andromeda style AIs capable of operating entire warships on their own.

Also, the concept of the Commonwealth itself is a direct parallel to the Federation.  In fact, the new Commonwealth that Hunt tries to build throughout the series is actually a federation of worlds, in terms of governmental system.

One stark difference between the shows is genetic manipulation.  In Trek, the practice was essentially banned after the eugenics wars, excepting for medical necessity.  However, in the Andromeda universe, genetic manipulation is nearly universal.  So much so, that almost all the main characters are somehow genetically enhanced and there is an entire race that has been enhanced and pursues genetic perfection.

So, there are plenty of parallels and equivalencies between the two series.  Enough to make you believe that the two are mirrors of each other.  However, there is no crossover between the two.  And, while many believe it was Roddenberry's intent to sequence 'Andromeda' after the fall of the Federation, this could also be a case of a single showrunner and writer recycling base concepts in new ways.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You spend a lot of time showing the similarities, so much so that your actual answer ("completely independent" and "no crossover") gets a bit lost.  The content of your answer is pretty interesting; I just think you should be a bit more emphatic about the "no." :)

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SF&F!  You mention "strong evidence" ... by this, do you mean that the similarities between the shows are evidence, or do you mean that there is other evidence (statements by people working on the shows, for example)?

Answer (score -1):

No. They aren't. Different races. Different technology.
I also heard the two pilots turned to one series theory. There have been several TV films (2 or 3) that each use a character named Dylan Hunt who ends up in a post-apocalyptic future. However, those are always set on earth. I think Andromeda took that story idea and combined it with another pilot about a starship (similar to Trek, but probably not related) and so the story became about a starship captain stranded in a post-apocalyptic galaxy. Actually most of the nuts and bolts were developed by DS9 writing alumni Robert Hewitt Wolfe. I don't know if races like the Nietzscheans or the Magog were Roddenberry's idea or Wolfe's. All I know is, that when Wolfe was essentially replaced with Sorbo, a whole 'nother mindset hit the show.

Comment: Can you provide any sources to support your answer?

Answer (score -2):

Well, let's keep in mind there isn't anything that disproves this hypothesis. There are a billion different species, civilizations, and galaxies across the Star Trek universe. Additionally, Roddenberry did wrote Andromeda as a post Federation star trek story. So this would definitely honor the author's original intent. At the end of the day, it all depends on what the studio decides to do and how much profitable it will be for them to merge the two.

Comment: Some points were made in [Tony Meyer's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6620/122024) that seem to contradict the theory. Also, Roddenberry originally intending _Andromeda_ to be a _Star Trek_ follow-up doesn't mean that's what it ended up being.

Answer (score -3):

It could be that they are related if you think of an alternate reality, similar to "The Mirror Universe" from the Original Star Trek Series and when The Next Generation did it similar but differant. It is really hard to say or sure what Gene had in mind for Andromeda, weather it was intended to have any realation to Star Trek, but if I had my guess about it I would say that he did intend on them to be related. They're similarities between the two are strikingly close. So speaking for my own opinion I have to say Yes...

Comment: Answers should generally be based on canonical facts and not opinions.

Comment: What similarities would they be?